# instantiate dynamic class

Tags: javascript, oop, class

In Javascript, how do you instantiate a new class dynamically without using eval() and pass in an argument?  For example,
let's say I want to create a new CatViewController and pass in "kitten", how would I do that?

```
var myClassname = "CatViewController";
var cat = new myClassname("kitten");
```

It should resolve to:

```
var cat = new CatViewController("kitten");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to show how and where the constructor function is defined in order for @Chaos to give a more precise answer. His generic examples show generally how it would work.

Answer (score 8):

As long as the function is within scope you can do this:

```
var cat = new this[myClassname]("kitten");
```

Another similar way:

```
var classes = {
    A: function (arg) {

    },
    B: function (arg) {

    },
    C: function (arg) {

    }
};

var a = new classes["A"]("arg");
```

Comment: That will only work if `this == window`, and the var is in the global scope.

Comment: @Matthew - That isn't quite correct. It can actually work within any scope but it must be defined within said scope.

Comment: What if you instantiate it inside another class where this != window?

Comment: This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VzA5W/3/) (fixed) shows that it doesn't work.  Note that it's not at the global scope, and (as in the question) not defined as `this.CatViewController = function(){}`.  So you get a "not a constructor" error.

Comment: Chaos: *"...but it must be defined within said scope."* I'd add that it must be defined as a public member within that scope. If defined with `var` it won't work, unless the scope is `window`. Unfortunately we don't know how it is defined. @Matthew: If you change your demo to use `this.CatViewController = func...` it will work. The constructor definition is absent from the question.

Comment: @patrick, but it must be using var or a regular function declaration.  If you define it like that the `new CatViewController` in the question wouldn't work (except at global scope).

Comment: On the other hand, [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UYGcm/1/) at the global scope, works fine.

Comment: @Matthew: *"but it's implicitly using var or a regular function declaration"* What is using var or a declaration? We don't know how the constructor is being defined. You're right that a function declaration, or an expression using `var` will make it unaccessible as a property (except in `window`). EDIT: [Your first demo, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/VzA5W/4/)

Comment: <strike>I mean `var CatViewController = function(){}` or `function CatViewController(){}`.  Only those two work with `new CatViewController`.  **Except**, he could be using `this.CatViewController` at global scope.</strike>

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, that's absolutely correct. But I don't think that OP cares about using the specific form `new CatViewController` so much as about the ability to instantiate a class where the class name is referenced in a variable. EDIT: Keep in mind that in your example, you're using an anonymous function invocation, so the scope is `window`.

Comment: @Patrick, you're right.  If you put in [the missing new](http://jsfiddle.net/j82uw/4/), it works (breaks) as I intended.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes indeed. But given that example, OP could use the solution @Chaos provided to instantiate a class from a String referenced by a variable, as long as it is from an accessible scope.

Comment: @patrick, very true.  I was just pointing out the `new CatViewController` syntax in the question might no longer work.

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, it took me a while to catch on to what you meant. My LCD has fried my brain for the evening. ;o) I'm pretty sure OP is ambivalent to the syntax though, as long as it can somehow be accomplished.

Comment: @Chaos: Sorry for the clutter under your answer. :o) +1 For the correct approach using square bracket notation (given the limited information provided). (Did I say "ambivalent" above? I meant "indifferent".)

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew - If you have reference to the `window` scope you should be good to go, right? Just use the `window` reference instead of the `this` keyword. Seems to be working for me. However I'm very curious if there are any downfalls to this approach since I'm currently using it in a project. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2KrD/) based on your previous demo.